# P5.JS: Collisions?

Tags: collision, p5.js

I have an idea of getting a circle grow in size if anywhere in the circle's area there is this object called "food". Though I have no idea how to implement it on my code. I have tried but of course the whole concept of my idea was off in trying to pull this off.

```
this.touch = function(){
    if (x > this.x && y > this.y){
        this.radius += 0.5;
    }
}
```

This is one of my functions in a constructor, the variable x and y is referencing the "food"'s position. The this.(variables) are referring to the object reacting to the food.

The code snippet on top does not work simply for the fact that I am asking the object to increase in size based on x and y positions, and that just doesn't work for my concept.

Can anyone give me some tips or send a link to something which could help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by googling something like **collision detection** for a ton of results.

You can also narrow your search by adding the type of shapes you're talking about. For example, if your food is shown as a point, you might google (point circle collision detection". If your food is shown as a circle, you might google "circle circle collision detection".

If you're dealing with circles, you basically want to check the distance from the center of the circle. If that distance is less than the radius of the circle, then you have a collision. The `dist()` function will come in handy here.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) is a tutorial on collision detection. It's written for Processing, but all of the concepts apply to P5.js as well.

Comment: The link was really helpful, now I feel like I'm just gonna practice this concept over and over and over again till it's part of me!

Comment: @NafizHisham Sounds like a good [programming kata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kata_(programming))!